# Output from JComboBox being printed twice

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jcombobox

I'm trying to get the selected value from the combo-box to display in a prompt window but the prompt window appears twice. I haven't duplicated any code but then why does it happen?

The code snippet :-

```
package interfaceGUI;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class BirthdayForm extends JFrame{
private JLabel chooseItem;
private JLabel chooseQuantity;
private JComboBox items;
private JTextField quantity;
private JTextArea selection;
private JButton Rent;
private JButton Edit;
private JButton Cancel;

private JPanel choose;
private JPanel forButton;

private String list[] = {"Chair", "Napkin", "Garland", "Mirrored Ball", 
"Floral Vases", "Large Balloons", "Square Jars"};

public BirthdayForm()
{
    super("Birthday Party Supplies Rental Form");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    chooseItem = new JLabel("Choose Item:");
    items = new JComboBox(list);

    chooseQuantity = new JLabel("Choose Quantity:");
    quantity = new JTextField(5);
    choose = new JPanel();
    choose.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    choose.add(chooseItem);
    choose.add(items);
    choose.add(chooseQuantity);
    choose.add(quantity);
    add(choose);

    selection = new JTextArea(15,30);
    add(selection);

    Rent = new JButton("Rent");
    Edit = new JButton("Edit List");
    Cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    forButton = new JPanel();
    forButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    forButton.add(Rent);
    forButton.add(Edit);
    forButton.add(Cancel);
    add(forButton);

    comboHandler handler = new comboHandler();
    items.addItemListener(handler);
}

public class comboHandler implements ItemListener
{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == items)
        {
            String item = (String) items.getSelectedItem();
            if(item == "Chair")
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chair" , "Items", 
                                         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

What did i do wrong? I can't find my mistake. Please help.

Comment: get the item state from the event and check if it is the state is selected, int state = event.getStateChange(); if(state == ItemEvent.SELECTED)

Comment: Can you provide a more complete answer please?

Comment: sure, see my answer, the itemStateChange gets fired twice one for the item that is being deselected and one for the item that being selected

Comment: A better choice might be to use an ActionListener instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the change you need, check if the item is selected,

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == items)
        {
            int state = event.getStateChange();
            if(state == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
              String item = (String) items.getSelectedItem();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item , "Items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: $Damini, I am not clear about your question, you want to if statement for the next item on the list, what do you want to show in regard to the next item on the list

Comment: That was a silly question sorry lol. I didn't look at your answer well. You solved my problem thanks a lot.

Comment: *"if(item == "Chair")"* - really?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for the heads up, I have just modified the code.  I was just trying to answer the question by modifying the code.  But it is true,with the if statement, the message dialog will only show when "chair" is selected.

Comment: I figured it was a copy/paste issue ;)